# Turning off MVC compilation debug for release builds

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, debugging

I have three config files for my MVC 5 project. `web.config`, `web.debug.config` and `web.release.config`.

I want to turn off `compilation debug` when running in release but cannot seem to get it to work.

In web.config

```
<compilation debug="true"/>
```

In web.release.config

```
<compilation debug="false"/>
```

When I run in release mode `HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled` is still equal to `true` (still attached to debugger though).

What am I doing wrong? I tried to take the tag out of the main `web.config` and put it into `web.debug.config` but the debugger just complained and asked me to put it back in to `web.config`

**Update**

My web.release.config looks like this

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
    <remove statusCode="404" />
    <error statusCode="404" path="/error/notfound" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    <remove statusCode="403" />
  <error statusCode="403" path="/error/forbidden" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
<system.web>
  <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
  <!--<compilation debug="false"/>-->
</system.web>
```

Comment: It may sound silly, but please try reset IIS.

Comment: I assume you mean restart and not reset?

Comment: Yes restart, but there's a iisreset command so I used a reset term...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `web.config`:

```
<compilation debug="true" ...
```

In your `web.release.config`:

```
<compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
```

This will set the `transform` on the `debug` attribute on the `compilation` tag, for `remov`ing it. You don't need to set any transform in your `web.debug.config` because, you would not want to change the config while in debug mode.

Once done that, publish (deploy) your project. To test it, publish your project to a folder and then open up the `web.config` there. You will see that the `web.config` has been transformed. Config-transforms are a deployment feature.

More info here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations

Comment: I actually had this before I realised it wasnt working. I tried again but to no avail. Any reason that this might not work?

Comment: @Chris: Your `web.release.config` should only contain things that you want to transform. By any chance, do you have other things there? I have also added a reference which shows it by example.

Comment: @Chris: I see now. Note that the transform works only when you publish your project. It will not work if you simply do a ctrl-F5 or run the project in release mode. Publish your project to a folder and then you will see that your `web.config` has been transformed. Transforms are a deployment feature.

Comment: Ah ok... When we install this we also don't get this working.  We install using WIX, would this count as a "publish" or do we need to do something when installed to ensure it transforms correctly?

Comment: @Chris: Oh.. It would be tricky because this transorm works on msbuild-deploy. I haven't used WiX since ages, but these links might help you there: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17655437 and/or http://stackoverflow.com/q/15377149

Comment: Thanks for the help. If it turned out I couldnt use transforms is there another way around this issue?

Comment: @Chris: I hope you have already gone thru the two references I gave above. Here are two more references for you: (1) http://blogs.planetsoftware.com.au/andy/archive/2011/06/21/web.config-transforms-xdt-with-visual-studio-setup-and-deployment-packages.aspx and (2) http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Using-web-config-transformations-in-WiX-td5018151.html . If you still have problems, please feel free to ask that as a new question, I am sure some WiX experts here might be able to help you.

Comment: @Abhitalks just FYI in case you hadn't already stumbled on to this - I was recently dealing w/all this config transform stuff and found out that you can get transforms working on BUILD (not just on DEPLOY). Here's the link in case you or anyone else is interested: http://sebnilsson.com/a5410281/asp-net-transform-web-config-with-debug-release-on-build/

Comment: Great! Thanks @ChrisEmerson.